# permanently disable gdb startup text

Tags: configuration, gdb

When debugging a program with `gdb` (`gdb main`), it shows a lot of credits, and links. I know that we can use the `quiet` argument to disable this text, but I want to disable it **permanently**. Does `gdb` have `init` file or anything else in order to change the behavior of `gdb`?

***Instead of:***

```sh
$ gdb main
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
...
```

***I want:***

```sh
$ gdb main
Reading symbols from main...
(No debugging symbols found in main)
(gdb)
```

Answer (score 11):

The patch alluded to by Tom Tromey above has been merged into gdb 11, it appears.

Put `set startup-quietly on` into an early initialization file (this is `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/gdb/gdbearlyinit`, `~/.config/gdb/gdbearlyinit` or `~/.gdbearlyinit`) and you will be good.

See the documentation here: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Initialization-Files.html#Initialization-Files

and here: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Mode-Options.html#index-set-startup_002dquietly

Answer (score 7):

At present, the only way to do this is to use `gdb -q` (aka `gdb --quiet`).  This will silence the startup message.  A typical way to do this is to use a shell alias.

There's a pending patch to add this feature to gdb.  However, it won't be available until at least GDB 11, expected sometime next year.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer from @tom-tromey , you can add an alias in your bashrc (or equivalent for whichever shell you use)

```bash
echo 'alias gdb="gdb -q"' >> ~/.bashrc
```